# C# for GUI and C++ main program

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I'm doing my coursework for my final year in school, I'm relatively new to coding. Only done a little bit of basic c++ in my first year.

My question is if its possible to use c# for my GUI and C++ for my main program and make it work together (compile?) If so, How should I go about doing it? I'm extremely new to this so I'm sorry if I got any terms wrong.

I've tried doing research on this but I can find something that actually helps me a lot for someone new like me.

EDIT: My project is together with my internship and my professor doesn't specialise in programming, 
Roughly what my program needs to do is that it needs to send out a signal to a digital input module which will light up a bulb in the module. I plan to receive the signal from the ground and record it into a local database if a signal was received. The database is suppose to record the serial number of that module tested with the results.There are a total of 64 lights in that module and i plan to soak test the module to prevent the anomaly.

Comment: I suggest you ask your professor/advisor. They'll probably have better advice for w/e you want to do

Comment: Yes it is possible. No it is not simple if you are a beginner with "_basic c++ in your first year = three years ago_". Why do you think you need both?

Comment: Compile them separately and communicate over a socket.

Comment: Its part of my project I'm to carry out, I'm basically on my own and I have 4 months to program this, or I fail. My course doesn't really specialize in programming but my final year project is about it. More information about my project can be seen in my edit.

Comment: care to comment on the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - yes, there are a couple of ways you could do it.

Longer answer - you really don't want to do this unless you have a specific need, particularly if you're a beginner at both C++ and C#.  Learning programming is hard in general without jumping into the advanced topics you'd need to actually make this work.

If you just want to do some simple GUI stuff and learn to get better at programming in general, I'd recommend just sticking with C#.

Comment: Its part of my project I'm to carry out, I'm basically on my own and I have 4 months to program this, or I fail. My course doesn't really specialize in programming but my final year project is about it. More information about my project can be seen in my edit. Thanks a lot

Comment: The additional information doesn't explain anything about why you're thinking you should do part of this in C# and part in C++.  Particularly given your lower level of experience and the short timeline, you're likely doubling your work effort by trying to do this partially in C++ and partially in C#.  You'll finish the project much faster if you pick one language - either language - and stick with it.